# In a QTableWidget, how to determine if an empty cell is editable?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtablewidget

I'm working on a QAction to paste structured text from the clipboard into a QTableWidget. This is my current code:

```
class PasteCellsAction(qt.QAction):
    def __init__(self, table):
        if not isinstance(table, qt.QTableWidget):
            raise ValueError('CopySelectedCellsAction must be initialised ' +
                             'with a QTableWidget.')
        super(PasteCellsAction, self).__init__(table)
        self.table = table
        self.setText("Paste")
        self.setShortcut(qt.QKeySequence('Ctrl+V'))
        self.triggered.connect(self.pasteCellFromClipboard)

    def pasteCellFromClipboard(self):
        """Paste text from cipboard into the table.

        If the text contains tabulations and
        newlines, they are interpreted as column and row separators.
        In such a case, the text is split into multiple texts to be paste
        into multiple cells.

        :return: *True* in case of success, *False* if pasting data failed.
        """
        selected_idx = self.table.selectedIndexes()
        if len(selected_idx) != 1:
            msgBox = qt.QMessageBox(parent=self.table)
            msgBox.setText("A single cell must be selected to paste data")
            msgBox.exec_()
            return False

        selected_row = selected_idx[0].row()
        selected_col = selected_idx[0].column()

        qapp = qt.QApplication.instance()
        clipboard_text = qapp.clipboard().text()
        table_data = _parseTextAsTable(clipboard_text)

        protected_cells = 0
        out_of_range_cells = 0

        # paste table data into cells, using selected cell as origin
        for row in range(len(table_data)):
            for col in range(len(table_data[row])):
                if selected_row + row >= self.table.rowCount() or\
                   selected_col + col >= self.table.columnCount():
                    out_of_range_cells += 1
                    continue
                item = self.table.item(selected_row + row,
                                       selected_col + col)
                # ignore empty strings
                if table_data[row][col] != "":
                    if not item.flags() & qt.Qt.ItemIsEditable:
                        protected_cells += 1
                        continue
                    item.setText(table_data[row][col])

        if protected_cells or out_of_range_cells:
            msgBox = qt.QMessageBox(parent=self.table)
            msg = "Some data could not be inserted, "
            msg += "due to out-of-range or write-protected cells."
            msgBox.setText(msg)
            msgBox.exec_()
            return False
        return True
```

I want to test if a cell is editable before pasting data in it, and for this I get the item using `QTableWidget.item(row, col)` and then I checks the flags of the item.

My problem is that the `.item` method returns `None` for empty cells, so I can't check the flags of empty cells. My code currently only works when there is no empty cell in the paste area.

The error is in lines 46 (`None` returned) and 50 (`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'flags'`):

```
            item = self.table.item(selected_row + row,
                                   selected_col + col)
            # ignore empty strings
            if table_data[row][col] != "":
                if not item.flags() & qt.Qt.ItemIsEditable:
                    ...
```

Is there another way of finding out if the cell is editable, other than checking flags of the item?

Comment: It returns `None` not because the cell is empty but because the cell doesn't exist

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this. I can visually see an empty cell in my table widget. Do you mean that as long as no data or flags are set in a cell, it does not exist as an item?

Comment: And if the answer is yes, does the inexistence of a cell guarantee that is is editable? Or could the user of my widget have write-protected it without creating an item?

Comment: Are you sure that `selected_row + row, selected_col + col` corresponds to the position of the cell that you see ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure of that. The action works when I paste the same data to the same location, as long as I make sure that I add some random text to all cells in the paste area prior to pasting.

Answer (score 3):

The dimensions of `QTableWidget` a can specified without explicitly adding any items. In which case, the cells will be completely empty - i.e. both the data and the item will be `None`. If the user edits the cell, the data will be added to the table's model, and an item will be added. This will happen even if the entered value is an empty string. By default, all cells will be editable unless you take explicit steps to make them read-only.

There are numerous ways of making cells read-only - for instance, [setting the edit triggers](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#editTriggers-prop), or overriding the tables's [edit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#edit-2) method. But if your **only** method is explicitly setting the flags on individual table-widget items, you can safely assume that a cell with no item is both editable and empty. (Note that if you directly set the data via the table's model rather than by using e.g. `setItem`, the cell will still automatically have an item).

Comment: I've switched to getting/setting the data via model rather than the widget, in order to make my actions work with QTableView as well as QTableWidget. This removes the need to work with items.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that seems to work: create a new item and add it to the table when the `item()` method returns `None`.

I still have some doubts abouts whether there is a risk that this might modify the flags of a write-protected cell. I currently just assume that if a cell is write-protected, this means that it necessarily already contains an item.

```
            item = self.table.item(target_row,
                                   target_col)
            # item may not exist for empty cells
            if item is None:
                item = qt.QTableWidgetItem()
                self.table.setItem(target_row,
                                   target_col,
                                   item)
            # ignore empty strings
            if table_data[row_offset][col_offset] != "":
                if not item.flags() & qt.Qt.ItemIsEditable:
                    protected_cells += 1
                    continue
                item.setText(table_data[row_offset][col_offset])
```

EDIT: `target_row = selected_row + row_offset` ...